# jQuery tripple nested menu with child menus

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, nested

i'm not getting forward in this so i need your help.

It's a triple nested menu for wordpress. And it looks like this:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="has_children">Link with children</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="has_children">Link with children</a>
                 <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class `has_children` to each link which has a `ul.sub-menu`.

My code now is:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('ul.sub-menu li').has('ul.sub-menu'), function() {
    jQuery('a', this).addClass('has_children');
})
```

That works for the first ul.sub-menu li but all other child links now have the class `has_children` even if they don't have a sub-menu.

EDIT [Solution]:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('ul.sub-menu li').has('ul.sub-menu'), function () {
jQuery('>a', this).addClass('has_children');
```

})

That did the trick! :) Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure your selector is actually hitting anything. You are querying for an li inside a ul which has another ul inside. That does not comform to the HTML you are showing. You are not showing ul>li>ul, your hTML is ul>ul as the inner uls are not inside lis but directly inside the ul.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Lj8xX/ -- however, your `html` is invalid.  The only tags allowed as children of `<ul>` are `<li>` tags.  `<ul>` cannot be a child of `<ul>`.  This may affect how your html is parsed and have weird effects in some browsers

Comment: I'm so sorry! Sure the uls are inside the lis! I've edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your selector to only match the direct `a` within the current `li` otherwise it will match all `a` within all levels. Use `>a` to match the direct `a` only, similar to this:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('ul.sub-menu li').has('ul.sub-menu'), function () {
    jQuery('>a', this).addClass('has_children');
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tNNmN/) - Matching only the `a` directly within the current `li`

---

In the DEMO I removed all the `has_children` classes you had in the initial HTML to show that indeed they are added as expected by the script.

Comment: Thank you very much! But $(this) is not working in my case. However just , this) did the trick. THANK YOU!! :)

Comment: @PascalCloverfield: Residue code from a previous try to resolve this, my bad. Didn't notice as it worked in the fiddle, I updated my answer for completeness to match your exact scenario. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj8xX/5/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link with children</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link with children</a> 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.sub-menu li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('ul').hasClass('sub-menu'))  $(this).find('a:first').addClass('has_children');
});
```